# I am getting this error : "The requested resource isn't a valid image for /images/crown.png received text/html; charset=utf-8"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, bootstrap-5

I am using Next.js and I got this error.This is the code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Container, Col, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import Image from "next/image";
export default function fs() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col lg="4" md="4">
            <Row>test</Row>
            <Row>test</Row>
            <Row>test</Row>
          </Col>
          <Col lg="4" md="4">
            <Image width="100%" height="50" src="/images/crown.png" />
          </Col>
          <Col lg="4" md="4">
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and after reviewing the code many times I've found that the images folder can't exist in the 'styles' folder , it should be in the 'public' folder (apparently  this is how Next.js architecture works !).

Answer (score 2):

according to Next.js architecture, there should be a folder called 'public'.You should put the images used in the app there, and not in any other folder like 'styles'.